# How to remove Next &raquo; and &laquo; Previous

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pagination

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU2Db.png)

this component for pagination

```
<li v-for="link in links" :key="link.label">
                <a v-if="link.url" @click="loadPage(link.label)"
                    :class="{ 'z-10 flex items-center justify-center px-3 py-2 text-sm leading-tight border text-primary-600 bg-primary-50 border-primary-300 hover:bg-primary-100 hover:text-primary-700 dark:border-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-white': link.active, 'flex items-center justify-center px-3 py-2 text-sm leading-tight text-gray-500 bg-white border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white': !link.active }">{{
                        link.label }}</a>
            </li>
            <li v-if="currentPage < lastPage">
                <a @click="loadPage(currentPage + 1)"
                    class="flex items-center justify-center h-full py-1.5 px-3 leading-tight text-gray-500 bg-white rounded-r-lg border border-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white">
                    <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10l-3.293-3.293a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
                            clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </li>
```

and this how to use pagination component

<pagination :currentPage="bookData.current_page" :lastPage="bookData.last_page" :total="bookData.total"
:from="bookData.from" :to="bookData.to" :links="bookData.links" @loadPage="loadData">

i want to remove text in pagination

Comment: Can you paste the important section of the code here?

Comment: is this a custom pagination component you made, or is it from a specific library?  Your code doesn't show where the pagination buttons come from, so it's impossible to say how to change their text labels.  you should review [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add more code and information to your question.